# Using WebAnimations API instead of neon-animation

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to add web animation to my app.
I want to avoid using neon-animation as it is now deprecated.

I read this instructions : https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/polymer-2-0-replace-neon-animation-with-web-animations-api-e82d7bd82e6 but I can't figure out how to use it in my case :

I have a page with two custom elements that are displayed if the route matches :

```
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/list" active="{{listActive}}"></app-route>
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/product/:id" active="{{productsActive}}" data="{{productsData}}"></app-route>

<catalog-product-page hidden$={{!productsActive}}></catalog-product-page>
<catalog-list-page id="productPage" hidden$={{!listActive}} item-route="{{route.prefix}}/product"></catalog-list-page>
```

The `catalog-list-page` contains a `dom-repeat` that loads a list of items pointing to a `catalog-product-page`.
How can I make `catalog-product-page` to get animated when an item is selected ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though `neon-animation` is already deprecated but it's still a good example of using Web Animations. I recommend you to look its source code especially `neon-animated-pages` and `neon-animatable`.

> How can I make `catalog-product-page` to get animated when an item is selected?

It has a lot of ways to do.

One of the simplest things I come up is [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/z02Tv8yOC5qD7q8DNH4E?p=preview). In that plunker it has 2 components are `my-app` and `my-page`. Switch to first version (versions on the sidebar) is just a simple toggle display block to none and so on. Then switch to second version you will see simple transition and the added code is

```
if (selected === this.selected) return

this.animate({
  opacity: [0, 1],
  transform: ['translateY(16px)', 'translateY(0)'] 
}, {
  duration: 250,
  easing: 'ease-in-out'
})
```

This mean for entry page (switch to selected) it will play animation as the code shown. For exit page (switch to not selected) it will do nothing because its display is none. For other pages just return.

More examples of using Web Animations see [here](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/blob/dev/docs/examples.md) and W3C specification see [here](http://w3c.github.io/web-animations/). I hope this help.

Note: In my experience of using Web Animations. It works very well in supported browsers but others it's not that good (you can find some issue on their repo).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I managed to get the animation on the first display of the page (when I refresh the browser) but then, when I switches beetween pages (from catalog list page to product detail page and vice versa), the animation is not loaded anymore. I have to digg a bit further about my elements lifecycle. I'll update my post asap.